# Using FlatFileItemReader and asynchronous processors

Tags: java, spring

I have a simple .csv file with ~400,000 line (one column only). It takes me a lot of time to read the records and process them.

The processor validating records against couchbase. The writer - writing into remote topic, takes me around 30 mins.

I read that `flatfileItemreader` is not thread-safe, so my chunk value is 1. I read the asynchronous processing could assist, but I can't see any improvements.

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class NotificationFileProcessUploadedFileJob {


    @Value("${expected.snid.header}")
    public String snidHeader;

    @Value("${num.of.processing.chunks.per.file}")
    public int numOfProcessingChunksPerFile;

    @Autowired
    private InfrastructureConfigurationConfig infrastructureConfigurationConfig;

    private static final String OVERRIDDEN_BY_EXPRESSION = null;


    @Inject
    private JobBuilderFactory jobs;

    @Inject
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Inject
    ExecutionContextPromotionListener executionContextPromotionListener;


    @Bean
    public Job processUploadedFileJob() throws Exception {
        return this.jobs.get("processUploadedFileJob").start((processSnidUploadedFileStep())).build();

    }

    @Bean
    public Step processSnidUploadedFileStep() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("processSnidFileStep")
                .<PushItemDTO, PushItemDTO>chunk(numOfProcessingChunksPerFile)
                .reader(snidFileReader(OVERRIDDEN_BY_EXPRESSION))
                .processor(asyncItemProcessor())
                .writer(asyncItemWriter())
            //    .throttleLimit(20)
             //   .taskJobExecutor(infrastructureConfigurationConfig.taskJobExecutor())


                        //     .faultTolerant()
                        //   .skipLimit(10) //default is set to 0
                        //     .skip(MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException.class)
                .build();
    }

    @Inject
    ItemWriter writer;

    @Bean
    public AsyncItemWriter asyncItemWriter() {
        AsyncItemWriter asyncItemWriter=new AsyncItemWriter();
        asyncItemWriter.setDelegate(writer);
        return asyncItemWriter;
    }


    @Bean
    @Scope(value = "step", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
    public ItemStreamReader<PushItemDTO> snidFileReader(@Value("#{jobParameters[filePath]}") String filePath) {
        FlatFileItemReader<PushItemDTO> itemReader = new FlatFileItemReader<PushItemDTO>();
        itemReader.setLineMapper(snidLineMapper());
        itemReader.setLinesToSkip(1);
        itemReader.setResource(new FileSystemResource(filePath));
        return itemReader;
    }


    @Bean
    public AsyncItemProcessor asyncItemProcessor() {

        AsyncItemProcessor<PushItemDTO, PushItemDTO> asyncItemProcessor = new AsyncItemProcessor();

        asyncItemProcessor.setDelegate(processor(OVERRIDDEN_BY_EXPRESSION, OVERRIDDEN_BY_EXPRESSION, OVERRIDDEN_BY_EXPRESSION,
                OVERRIDDEN_BY_EXPRESSION, OVERRIDDEN_BY_EXPRESSION, OVERRIDDEN_BY_EXPRESSION, OVERRIDDEN_BY_EXPRESSION));
        asyncItemProcessor.setTaskExecutor(infrastructureConfigurationConfig.taskProcessingExecutor());

        return asyncItemProcessor;

    }

    @Scope(value = "step", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
    @Bean
    public ItemProcessor<PushItemDTO, PushItemDTO> processor(@Value("#{jobParameters[pushMessage]}") String pushMessage,
                                                             @Value("#{jobParameters[jobId]}") String jobId,
                                                             @Value("#{jobParameters[taskId]}") String taskId,
                                                             @Value("#{jobParameters[refId]}") String refId,
                                                             @Value("#{jobParameters[url]}") String url,
                                                             @Value("#{jobParameters[targetType]}") String targetType,
                                                             @Value("#{jobParameters[gameType]}") String gameType) {
        return new PushItemProcessor(pushMessage, jobId, taskId, refId, url, targetType, gameType);
    }

    @Bean
    public LineMapper<PushItemDTO> snidLineMapper() {
        DefaultLineMapper<PushItemDTO> lineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<PushItemDTO>();
        DelimitedLineTokenizer lineTokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
        lineTokenizer.setDelimiter(",");
        lineTokenizer.setStrict(true);
        lineTokenizer.setStrict(true);
        String[] splittedHeader = snidHeader.split(",");
        lineTokenizer.setNames(splittedHeader);
        BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<PushItemDTO> fieldSetMapper = new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<PushItemDTO>();
        fieldSetMapper.setTargetType(PushItemDTO.class);

        lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(lineTokenizer);
        lineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(new PushItemFieldSetMapper());
        return lineMapper;
    }
}


 @Bean
    @Override
    public SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor taskProcessingExecutor() {
        SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor simpleAsyncTaskExecutor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
        simpleAsyncTaskExecutor.setConcurrencyLimit(300);
        return simpleAsyncTaskExecutor;
    }
```

How do you think I could improve the processing performances and make them faster?

Comment: Javadoc of SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor has a big warning that recommends a thread-pooling TaskExecutor.

Answer (score 1):

A few things to note here:

I don't think the actual slowness comes from reading the file, because this flatfile of only one column should be read as fast as you can write pretty much, I don't think it's the bottleneck in your case. It's much more likely that writing to your datasource is causing the slowdown. Can you verify that? I also of **commit-interval** in your config, a high number will make it much much faster. If you are using a commit interval of something like 1, it will be painfully slow. Please refer to [this thread](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/batch/85671-multi-threaded-flatfileitemreader?p=512814#post512814).

If you are absolutely positive that reading the file is the bottleneck, you can always implement the first step as "partitioner" and then instead using the `FlatFileItemReader`, use one of the partitioning readers [in the next step](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/scalability.html). This will be thread safe.

Comment: ill need to split my big input file into small ones before right?

Answer (score 1):

commit-interval in 100-1000 would help you for sure. I implemented task executor in a similar case. But since a batch reader was too dependent on a number of pre-conditions, multiple requests never hampered the result data and performance improvement was manifold. Maybe you can test your corner cases and try testing code with executor with appropriate thread pool size.